# Java: Is there a way, how I can import a file which is in the same folder as the .jar?

Tags: java, file, filereader

The thing is, I am looking for a codeline which can import a txt file which is in the same folder as the .jar. The only problem is, the path where the jar and the txt file will be is unknown. So I am searching for a method which can return me the path of the .jar file which is at the same time the path of the txt. But it has to work with an outstanding .jar file and not only in console.
Would appreciate some helpful answers because I tried so many not working ways until now.

Comment: What's the structure of the JAR?  In other words, where is the .class file that reads the text file located in the JAR?  I'm assuming that the text file is located outside of the JAR.

Comment: @gilbert why is that relevant?

Comment: Because I need to see the JAR directory tree to get the proper amount of */..* to add to the file path of the text file.